# What does the author mean here by referring to this character as 'the possibility and the promise'?

Tags: meaning, literature

So I've come across this strange phrase in a novel I've been reading.

"Jim was splashing water on the girls. He was the Water God and they loved him. **He was the possibility and the promise.** He was great. He knew how to do it."

The context is that the narrator is jealously watching his friend impress a group of girls at a beach.

Now at first I assumed it meant that the girls viewed Jim as a potentially promising relationship, but I'm not so sure. Due to its strange phrasing I feel that I'm missing something.

Text is from the novel 'Ham on Rye' by Charles Bukowski.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The main problem might be looking at that as literal prose when in fact it's figurative poetry… even if it happens to be embedded in prose text.

Broadly, the phrase means both as much and as little as "I am the alpha and the omega". Somewhere in between, my own interpretation would be that it meant pretty-much the same. (https://www.google.com/search?q=i+am+the+alpha+and+the+omega+meaning&rlz=1C5CHFA_enGB779GB779&oq=i+am+the+alpha+and+the+&aqs=chrome.4.0j69i57j46j0l5.6274j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: I'm sorry, but what do you mean by 'somewhere in between'?

Comment: Sorry, Wayne: somewhere in between the alpha and the omega; between the beginning and the end, the first and the last, as much and as little…